# XSLT calling template with xsl:with-param on different template

Tags: xslt

I have a problem in my real-time XSLT files. Based on that, i am putting my question here.
I have 3 xslt files such as `1.xsl`, `2.xsl` and `master.xsl`. This `master.xsl` is imported into `1.xsl` and `2.xsl`

On the master.xsl, i am using this below code

```
<xsl:call-template name="content">
<xsl:with-param name="request" select="$request"/>
<xsl:call-template>
```

Like wise, on the `1.xsl`,

```
<xsl:template name="content">
<xsl:param name="request" as="node()"/>
....
</xsl:template>
```

On the `2.xsl`

```
<xsl:template name="content">

....
</xsl:template>
```

When, I am executing this `2.xsl`, i am getting the following error:

`XTSE0680: Parameter request is not declared in the called template`

Actually, the request variable is only needed when i execute `1.xsl`. Also, i do not declare dummy variable on the template on `2.xsl`. Like this, i have many xslt files in real time. So that, i am not able to declare same variable in many xslt files as it will more time and it wont be consistent.

Could anyone give me an idea to overcome this?

Comment: For testing purpose can you provide 3 of these XSL files which some dummy data? So that we can look at it

Comment: "As long as the parameter is declared in the called template, you're fine; leaving them out of the call just allows them to take the default value, which can be very useful." You may check it [here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200603/post50460.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well the rules for XSLT 2.0 clearly say in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTSE0680: "In the case of xsl:call-template, it is a static error to pass a non-tunnel parameter named x to a template that does not have a template parameter named x, unless backwards compatible behavior is enabled for the xsl:call-template instruction.".

Thus with XSLT 2.0 if you want to use the code

```
<xsl:call-template name="content">
<xsl:with-param name="request" select="$request"/>
<xsl:call-template>
```

then you need to make sure any called template `content` has that parameter `request` declared.

The rules for `apply-templates` are different I think so you could check whether you can't simply write a template with a `match` attribute and use `apply-templates`.

Comment: Actually, the xslt files, i cant change anything from <xsl:template name="content"> to <xsl:apply-template>. These have been modified by other people, i am just following the things the way they made it earlier. So, i am looking for some option that may not affect the current one.  Any idea? please